# c++ exceptions, should the caller add the context or provide it to the callee?

Tags: design, c++, exceptions, error-handling

Here is a piece of code. Basically, I load some source files, all of them are compiled separately, and then I link all of them.

```
LinkedObject loadObject(std::vector<std::string>& fileNames)
{
    std::vector<CompiledObject> objects;
    for(const std::string& fileName : fileNames)
    {
        std::string source = loadSourceFromFile(fileName);
        objects.push_back(CompiledObject(fileName, source));
    }
    return LinkedObject(fileNames, objects);
}
```

`loadSourceFromFile` needs the file name, and will throw an exception with an accurate message of what happens, and from which file.

`CompiledObject` and `LinkedObject` will do the same, but they don't need the file names. So I pass these as arguments only for the sake of giving more context to exception messages.

Of course, some other kind of exceptions may be throw in the process.

Maybe it doesn't matter for this example, since the "context" here is only one/several strings, but I don't like it. The way I see it caller should be responsible for adding the context if the callee doesn't have access to that.

But this is the only sane way I've found to not pollute the function with error-related code. Other ways would require me add several `try`/`catch` blocks and define exception types.

```
LinkedObject loadObject(std::vector<std::string>& fileNames)
{
    try
    {
        std::vector<CompiledObject> objects;
        for(const std::string& fileName : fileNames)
        {
            std::string source = loadSourceFromFile(fileName);

            try
            {
                objects.push_back(CompiledObject(source));
            }
            catch(CustomException& e)
            {
                // throw std::runtime_error with more context
            }
        }
        return LinkedObject(objects);
    }
    catch(CustomException& e)
    {
        // rethrow std::runtime_error with more context
    }

}
```

Which is way less readable than the previous one, and requires custom exception types.

Should the caller handle the context, to the cost of having harder to read code? Or should the caller provide the context? Or maybe there I'm not using the correct error handling mecanism in this case, and should use something else (eg `std::expected`)?

Comment: Your original code can be decluttered some (and support the exceptions better) if the class returned by `loadSourceFromFile` would store the filename within the class.  Then `CompiledObject` would be able to access it when handling errors.

Comment: loadSourceFromFile returns a std::string (I just edited the post to avoid further confusion). But even if it was a class, it would require me to add a member and its getter even tho it won't be used my the class. It's no different than passing the file name as an argument. Also I don't see what it changes to exception handling in the first case.

Comment: Arguably the file name is a property of the source.  Since it is useful for error reporting (and debugging), it should be retained as part of the source object IMHO.  Otherwise you have to pass around the filename, which can be problematic.

Comment: But then the CompiledObject, whose job is to compile source code, becomes coupled with the source format. What if the source doesn't come from a single file anymore, but from a compressed archive? Then I have to modify the CompiledObject class to add support for another object, in order to have relevant error message. Some goes if the source comes from an hardcoded std::string.

Comment: Your code is the same in both cases: `CompiledObject(filename, source)`.  I assume you intended that the `filename` parameter would be omitted in the `try/catch` case, so as to be added by the catch/rethrow?

Comment: You're right, I forgot to remove them. It's now edited, thanks.